# How can I convert jQuery ajax to fetch?

Tags: javascript, jquery, fetch-api, custom-wordpress-pages

This was my jQuery code before. Now I want to change it to fetch.

```
    function fetch(){
    jQuery.ajax({
        url: '<?php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php'); ?>',
        type: 'post',
        data: { action: 'data_fetch', keyword: jQuery('#keyword').val(), pcat: jQuery('#cat').val() },
        success: function(data) {
            jQuery('#datafetch').html( data );
        }
    });
}
```

I have changed the code to this now but I am getting bad request 400 status code

```
document.querySelector('#keyword').addEventListener('keyup',()=>{
    let data = {
    action: 'data_fetch',
    keyword: document.querySelector("#keyword").value
};
let url = "<?php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php'); ?>";
fetch(url, {
        method: 'POST', // or 'PUT'
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(data),
    })
    .then((response) => response.text())
    .then((data) => {
        document.querySelector("#datafetch").innerHTML = data;
    })
    .catch((error) => {
        console.error('Error:', error);
    });
})
```

Am I missing something? It is from WordPress if this helps somehow.

Comment: 400 means Bad Request. Usually server provides additional details on what is wrong. Start with comparing two requests using dev tools. Currently you are not sending `pcat` for example, this might be required by the server.

Comment: other than the argument `pcat` . does the code look good to you .. ? i mean conversion to  js fetch

Comment: LGTM. You need to debug both requests using dev tools. I'd copy both requests as curl and compare them.

Answer (score 1):

1. You forgot the pcat property in the data object
2. jQuery, by default, sends form encoded data, not JSON encoded data. Use a [URLSearchParams object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams) instead of a string of JSON and omit the content-type header (the browser will add the correct one for you).

Answer (score 0):

In your jQuery code you defined `data` as

```
data: { action: 'data_fetch', keyword: jQuery('#keyword').val(), pcat: jQuery('#cat').val() },
```

and in fetch you defined it as

```
let data = {
    action: 'data_fetch',
    keyword: document.querySelector("#keyword").value
};
```

so, you are not passing some value which was previously passed. No wonder that your server errors out. Let's change your code to

```
let data = {
    action: 'data_fetch',
    keyword: document.querySelector("#keyword").value,
    pcat: document.getElementById("cat").value
};
```

and try this out. If it still works, then you will need to find out what differs in the request and make sure that the request you are sending via fetch is equivalent to the request you formally sent via jQuery, then it should work well, assuming that the client-side worked previously with jQuery and the server-side properly handled the requests.